# Find the position of dragged object before drop

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript, I would like to reposition an object using a event drag.

Is tracking the distance the mouse moved the only way of getting the location of the object before drop?

In this example, there is not "drop location" as I will simply be updating the object's location based on where the user drags the mouse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cross Browser compatibility is an issue so the code is kind of funky.  This code should work on any Browser.

This is based on the mouseup event.
You could use the mousemove event instead.

If the event listener is added to the window, it will not work in IE8 and prior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Floor Plan</title>
<style type="text/css">
#page{width:100%;padding:0;}
</style>
<body><div id="page" onmouseup="fpos(event)">
</div></body></html>
EOT;
ob_flush();
echo <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var fp = document.getElementById('fp');
var ptr = document.getElementById('point');
function fpos(e) {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY){
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
  }
  else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)   {
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  var offSet = findPos(fp);
  x -=  offSet[0];
  y -=  offSet[1];
  find(x,y);
}
function findPos(obj) {
var currentLeft = currentTop = 0;
if (obj.offsetParent) {
do {
  currentLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
  currentTop += obj.offsetTop;
} while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
return [currentLeft,currentTop];
}}
```